# Sticker font - what is it?

Tags: fonts, font-identification, typefaces

Searched a number of tools both automatic and manual and can't identify what this font is.  Closest I came were an OCR (but the numbers were wrong) or New Letter Gothic - but that didnt have matching numbers (2, 3, 4, 9).

Thanks for any help and anyone who can figure this out!

[image]

Comment: In the future, you can also try MyFont's font identification service: [What the Font](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/).

Answer (score 10):

That is [Officina Sans](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/itc/officina-sans/). Designed by Erik Spiekermann and distributed by ITC. Quite popular in the late 90s.

[image]

Comment: And in German-speaking countries. At least in Germany and Austria, this typfeace is *all over the place*